# Invalid Syntax error on try clause in Python

Tags: python, mysql, google-cloud-platform

First I apologize if this is formatted poorly, I've never asked a question here before.

I'm running python 2.7.15 in a virtualenv on win10-64. I'm trying to upload some test strings to a MySQL database but I'm getting the dumbest error and I don't know how to get around it. The MySQL Python/Connector should be installed correctly. Same with the GCP SDK.

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode

# Config info will be moved into config file(s) after testing

# Google Proxy Connection (Proxy must be running in shell)
# C:\Users\USER\Google Drive\Summer Education\GCP
# $ cloud_sql_proxy.exe -instances="pdf2txt2sql-test"=tcp:3307
config1 = {
  'user': 'USER',
  'password': 'PASSWORD',
  'host': 'IP',
  'port': '3307',
  'database': 'pdftxttest',
  'raise_on_warnings': True,
}

# Direct Connection to Google Cloud SQL
config2 = {
  'user': 'USER',
  'password': 'PASSWORD',
  'host': 'IP',
  'database': 'pdftxttest',
  'raise_on_warnings': True,
}

try:
  cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**config1)
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
  if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
    print("Something is wrong with your user name or password")
  elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
    print("Database does not exist")
  else:
    print(err)
    print("Connection not made")

cursor = cnx.cursor()

# Test information
id = str(1)
testtitle = str("Look a fake title")
teststring = str('thislistis representingaveryshort pdfwithfuckedup spaces')

add_pdf = ("INSERT INTO pdftexttest (id, title, text) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (id, testtitle, teststring)

try:
  cursor.execute(add_pdf)
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
  if err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_TABLE_ERROR:
    print("no pdf for you")
  else:
    print(err)
    print("here")

cnx.commit()

cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

After running this code I get

```
(env) C:\Users\USER\Google Drive\Summer Education\ProjPdf2Txt>python TXT2SQL.py
  File "TXT2SQL.py", line 47
    try:
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have some previous experience in java but I'm still a novice programmer.

If I remove the Try...Except clause and go straight to cursor.execute() the console tells me

```
(env) C:\Users\USER\Google Drive\Summer Education\ProjPdf2Txt>python TXT2SQL.py
  File "TXT2SQL.py", line 46
    cursor.execute(add_pdf)
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: check your indentation

Comment: Since you're newbie I would recommend using a syntax highlighter UI. Using a Sublime Text or Atom as this will help you learn and find little nuances like this.

Comment: @Kyle Please don't update the code to correct it according to the answers you got, the question doesn't make sense anymore if you do. I reversed your edit.

Comment: @Thierry that makes sense thanks. I'll keep that in mind for future posts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were missing a parentesis there.

add_pdf = ("INSERT INTO pdftexttest (id, title, text) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (id, testtitle, teststring)**)**

Answer (score 1):

In previous line

add_pdf = ("INSERT INTO pdftexttest (id, title, text) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (id, testtitle, teststring)

You open ( but didn't close it.